# Silverlight based gadget to open link in a browser?

Tags: silverlight, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have written a sidebar gadget which displays a series of links using silverlight.  I can host the silverlight in a web site and when I click on the links they open in a new tab.  When I package it up as a gadget however the links appear in the gadget, and they can be clicked on, but they do not open a browser window to display the link.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to launch external links from gadgets using your preferred shell execute method; doing so will launch them in the default browser.  When developing gadgets, all my links have an onclick handler which points to the following method:

```
function launchLink() {
    if (this.href.slice(0,7) == "http://") {
        System.Shell.execute(this.href);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Theoretically, you could modify this slightly and invoke it from your Silverlight code using the HTML bridge.

**JS code**

```
function launchLink(href) {
    System.Shell.execute(href);
}
```

**Silverlight**

```
// HtmlPage requires using System.Windows.Browser
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("launchLink", "http://some.com/");
```

Comment: Thanks Andy E.  Turns out I didn't need the `HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this); ` bit (this just makes managed object visible to javascript), and just needed to shell execute by calling the javascript method.

Comment: @Sam: I kind of thought so but wasn't too sure.  My Silverlight knowledge isn't what it could be :-)